# Tabla desaparece al insertarla dentro de un While (php)

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de llamar unos rows de una tabla mysql dentro de un while, pero al envolver el tr dentro del while, la tabla desaparece y solo me deja los nombres del thead, pero desde ahi hasta abajo todo desaparece.

```
<section class="container">
    <h1 class="my-3">Adminsitrador de archivos</h1>
    <table class="table" id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">ARCHIVO</th>
          <th scope="col">TAMAÑO</th>
          <th scope="col">BORRAR</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php include_once('conexion.php'); ?>
      <?php
      $query= " INSERT INTO `archivos` (`nombre_archivo`,`tamano_archivo`) VALUES ('{$fileName}','{$fileSize}')";
      $resource = $conn->query($query);
      $total = $resource->num_rows;
      while ($row = $resource->fetch_assoc()){  ?>
        <tr>
          <td><? $row['nombre_archivo']; ?></td>
          <td><? $row['tamano_archivo']; ?></td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
```

Comment: para imprimir el valor te hace falta echo, p.e.  <td><? echo $row['nombre_archivo']; ?></td>

Comment: Ahora lo hice, pero el while no me muestra la tabla, como que desaparece todo al meter los tr dentro de ciclo.

```
while ($row = $resource->fetch_assoc()){  ?>
        <tr>
          <td><? echo $row['nombre_archivo']; ?></td>
          <td><? echo $row['tamano_archivo']; ?></td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
```

Comment: Igual veo que esta haciendo un INSERT en vez de un SELECT, como tal el INSERT no devuelve resultados al fetch_assoc, para imprimir datos debes tener una consulta SELECT

Comment: Verifica que los `<th>` son 4 y los `<td>` son 3 sin un `colspan`, lo cual hace una tabla mal formada. Adicional [no es aconsejado](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) abrir PHP con las etiquetas cortas `<?`, utilizar `<?php` en su lugar. Y finalmente si quieres mostrar el resultado de una consulta, debe ser un SELECT, no de un INSERT. Este último solo devolverá `true` o `false`.

Comment: Adicionalmente: No es sano por más que php y html lo admitan hacer sopa con el código (o potaje de brujas) puedes preparar todo los que va a salir dentro de un par de variables con php y luego volcarlo. Garantizas legibilidad y el control de errores se hace más simple.

Comment: lo podria dejar asi :  <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</th>
          <td><? echo $row['nombre_archivo']; ?></td>
          <td><? echo $row['tamano_archivo']; ?></td>
          <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

o donde va el echo row, puedo hacer solo un echo de una variable?

Comment: Acabo de revisar. Y tienes varios problemas. 1. La etiqueta corta debe usarse con la forma `<?= $valor ?>` cuando quieres hacer `echo $valor` te falta el `=` 2. Tienes 4 encabezados y envías tres columnas (ya te lo dijo @aeportugal) está mal formada la tabla **(se va a ver fea)** 3. Usas un query INSERT no un SELECT de modo que no tienes valores a mostrar. Necesitas consultar cómo queda la tabla para mostrarla y no lo haces.

Comment: Adicionalmente, muestra como se llama tu columna de ids para poder hacer ajustes y ofrecerte una idea de solución correcta

Comment: no se como puedo mostrar de mejor manera el codigo aqui

Comment: Edita tu código e incluye en un comment `\\ comentario` el nombre del campo id de la tabla `archivos` . También hace falta que indiques qué framework estás usando para ejecutar la consulta (si usas alguno) y, cuantas líneas de archivos quieres mostrar porque no has hecho una consulta para obtenerlas. En tu código aparece una consulta de adición. **verifica con `var_dump($row);`** y te vas a dar cuenta de que `$row = $resource->fetch_assoc()` no está entregando lo que esperas.